# Bridge to Kubernetes failed to find services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, amazon-eks

I am trying to get Bridge to Kubernetes to work with my aws eks cluster. I have the command line kubectl cmds working and can communicate to my eks cluster in vscode via the Kubernetes extension. So I believe my .kube/config is correct. When I hit "Kubernetes: Debug (Local Tunnel)" -> I get an error:

`Failed to configure Bridge to Kubernetes: Failed to find any services running in the namespace <correct_namespace> of cluster <correct_cluster>`

What am I missing? Everything I've seen shows that bridge to Kubernetes should be able to connect. Is there an additional EKS security policy Bridge to Kubernetes requires to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be that I did not set the default namespace. Vscode Kubernetes extension will use the default namespace when it tries to execute bridge to kubernetes cmds. When I was testing via cmd line I would always do `-n <namespace>` to specify the namespace